# Function that sends $\sum_{i=0}^n x^i$ to $\sum_{i=0}^n x^{-i}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometric-series

Is there a known function $f(S,x)$ that takes

$$S=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4+\dots + x^n$$

and $x$ as its input and returns

$$S'=1+\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{x^2}+\frac{1}{x^3}+\frac{1}{x^4}+\dots+\frac{1}{x^n} \ $$
for $x \in$ **R**, $x>0$ and $n>0$?

**Edit**: Simply evaluating $S(\frac{1}{x})$ is disallowed, as mentioned in the comments. I am looking for a more elegant formula, which does not require knowledge of $n$.

Comment: So $f(S)=S(1/x)$ is not allowed?

Comment: If $x = 0$ the first one gives 1, the second does not exist...

Comment: Right, I'm looking for a function in which S is an independent variable.

Comment: @saulspatz It looks like you are talking about the result on infinite sums. The sums in the question look finite.

Comment: Well, given $S$ you can, in principle, solve for $x$ as $S=\frac {x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}\implies x^{n+1}-Sx-S-1=0$.  Then you can compute $S'$.  Won't be elegant.

Comment: @Gibbs You're right.  My bad.

Comment: @Gibbs Thanks. I have edited the domain of S.

Comment: Correction:  meant to type $x^{n+1}-Sx+S-1=0$.

Comment: What does it mean to 'use $S$ as a variable in a nontrivial way'?  I don't see what is wrong with Alex R's answer.

Comment: @Jair Taylor $S$ should be treated as a number, not as a function. For example, if you knew the value of $S$ and $x$ but not $n$, is there a known function to find $S'$?

Comment: If it helps, I should state that such a function does exist. This post, however, is simply asking whether or not this function is known.

Comment: @user A more elegant solution exists.

Comment: @MasterDrifter May I assume that you know the solution?

Comment: @user I know the solution, yes.

Comment: @MasterDrifter If so, you probably know that the function is not well-defined for even $n$. How do you circumvent this problem?

Comment: @user I did not encounter this problem in my derivation. Care to elaborate?

Comment: For even $n$ there exists $S_*$, such that a) for $S<S_*$ there are no real x satisfying the relations and b) for $S>S_*$ there are always two distinct real values of $x$, and correspondingly two distinct values of $S'$.

Comment: Apologies, $x$ should have been defined only for positive values in the op. It has been fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following formula inverts the terms of the geometric series $\displaystyle{S=\sum_{i=0}^nx^i}$ independent of n:
$$S'=\frac{x}{\frac{1}{S}+x-1}.$$

As should be clear,
$$S'=\sum_{i=0}^nx^{-i}=\frac{S}{x^n}.$$
Since $S$ is a geometric series, $S=\frac{1-x^n}{1-x}$ and
$$
\begin{align}
1-x^n &= (1-x)S \\
x^n &= 1-S+xS \\
n &= \log_x(1-S+xS).
\end{align}
$$
Therefore,
$$
\begin{align}
S' &=\frac{S}{x^n} \\
&=\frac{S}{x^{\log_x(1-S+xS)}} \\
&= \frac{S}{1-S+xS} \\
&= \frac{x}{\frac{1}{S}+x-1}
\end{align}
$$
for $x \in$ **R** and $x>0, n\geq 0$.

Comment: I had initially come to this formula by a more roundabout method and so had made this post to see if there was a more straightforward proof already known to reach the same conclusion. However, while waiting for others to answer, I found the solution myself as posted here.

Comment: What about $S'(S,n) $?

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question, the answer is "no."  The function can't be well-defined.  For instance:

$$f(7) = f(1+2+4) = 1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{4} = \frac{7}{4}.$$

But

$$f(7) = f(1+6) = 1 +\frac{1}{6} = \frac{7}{6}.$$

Comment: For this reason, $f$ must also account for the $x$ for which $S$ is defined.

Comment: Then $f$ will have to be a function of two variables.  Either $S$ and $x$ or at least $S$ and $n$.  And if you allow two variables, the problem is trivial.

Comment: Feel free to post your answer for $f(S, x)$. However, if your solution is to simply compute every term of $S'$, it will not be awarded. I am looking for a more elegant approach. Hint: one does not need to know or solve for $n$.